# How can I make an icon not visible but still retain its dimensions?

Tags: html, css

I can use the visible property to hide an icon from view but then it seems that the width of the icon goes to zero. How can I make it so the icon cannot be see but have it still use space ?

Comment: i think that's the difference between visibility: hidden; and display:none. use the first one to achieve what you are looking for. example: http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/blfaqhidden.htm

Comment: This question would be clearer if you included a small example of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options you can go with.

1. `visibility:hidden;` which will hide the element and gives the space allotted.
2. `opacity:0;` which will make the element turn pale and still have its place.

Additional Info:you may vary the value between 0 and 1 to change its transperancy.

Answer (score 1):

Display none will not give any space to the element & element will behave as if it is not present in the HTML . Although it will be accessable by dom

In you case

```
         Visibility:hidden //just paste it in css property of the icon
```

is the requirement

The visibility :hidden make the element invisible but it still retain it dimensions .

It is very important interview question for css

Answer (score 0):

> *visibility*
>   The visibility property specifies whether the boxes
>   generated by an element are rendered.
>
> **Values**
>
> *hidden* 
>   The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is
>   drawn), **but still affects layout**. Furthermore, descendants of the
>   element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

```
visibility: hidden;
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
display:none; // hide the icon
display:block; // show the icon
```